# Switch is not clickable inside CollapsingToolbarLayout on android 5.+

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a CollapsingToolbarLayout and I put  an android.widget.Switch inside. So on Android 4.3 this switch is clickable and I can do whatever I want with it, but on Android 5.+ it is not clickable. Adding clickable = "true" for both Switch and CollapsingToolbarLayout made no effect.  `

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/appBar"
    >

<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="352dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
    app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"

    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        >
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    <ImageView
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/pillImage"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
        android:maxHeight="192dp"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="12dp">
    <Switch
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Отслеживать"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"
        android:id="@+id/switchInsideCollapsingLayout"


        />
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>`
```

Why Switch isn't clickable on 5.+ androids and how can I make it clickable for 5.+ versions of android.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what your question is exactly, could you post it.  It makes it a little easier for people to know they are answering the right question.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for you comment, @RickSmith, I have edited my question.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, I put an ImageView inside the CollapsingToolbarLayout and set it clickable, but nothing happens when I click it.

Answer (score 2):

Add elevation in your Image View or Switch
it Worked For me

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    app:expanded="false"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="140dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
        <LinearLayout
            android:elevation="25dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:tint="#ffffff"
                android:src="@drawable/volume"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSeekBar
                android:clickable="true"
                android:progressBackgroundTint="@color/progressBackground"
                android:progressTint="@color/progress"
                android:thumbTint="@color/thump"
                android:progress="55"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Watch the Attachments

[Screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pX3jX.jpg)
[Screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYQff.jpg)

Comment: after so much searching, only thing that worked for me. Bravo